# draggable span not being draggable after being Appended

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(".draggable").draggable();
$(".face").droppable({
  drop: function(event, ui) {
    $(".draggable").each(function(){
  $(this).draggable();
});
    $(ui.draggable).animate({
        fontSize: 0
    },1000,function() {
        $(".itemContainer").append(
          "<span class='draggable' id='" +
            $(ui.draggable).attr("id") +
            "'>" +
            $(ui.draggable).html() +
            "</span>"
        );
      }
    );
    if (ui.draggable.attr("id") == "homework") {
      gradeLevel("+=20");
      sLevel("+=25");
      socialLevel("-=20");
    } else if (ui.draggable.attr("id") == "meme") {
      sLevel("-=20");
      socialLevel("+=10");
      gradeLevel("-=15");
    } else if (ui.draggable.attr("id") == "hang") {
      sLevel("-=30");
      socialLevel("+=20");
      gradeLevel("-=20");
    }
    checkLevel();
  }
});

<div class="center">
<div class="bar sui">
<div class="barFilled s"></div>
</div>
<div class="bar gra">
<div class="barFilled grade"></div>
</div>
<div class="bar soc">
<div class="barFilled social"></div>
</div>
<div class="face">
<div class="eyelid"></div>
<div class="eye first"></div>
<div class="eyelid"></div>
<div class="eye second"></div>
<div class="mouth"></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="itemContainer">
<p class="dragEx">Drag and Drop Items onto His Face to Affect his Life<br />(Click me to go away)</p>
<span class="draggable" id="meme">Look at a Meme</span>
 <span class="draggable" id="homework">Do Homework</span>
 <span class="draggable" id="hang">Go out with friends</span>
 </div>
```

I am trying to make it so when a span is dragged on a div, it disappears then appends a new span to the container.  All the appending works fine its just it does not have the draggable affect from before it is dragged onto the div.

Comment: your HTML code?

Comment: I've updated the above all you can see my HTML

Comment: seems fine to me? https://jsfiddle.net/9j3ofyLf/ @Stuart Fong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st there is a problem in your code, you append the element with id which creates element with the same id, but id must be unique. You might want to update all your id like home, hang to `class="home"` etc.

Otherwise, when you call `$('#home')` to get element with id home you will only get the 1st match (even though there are more than 1)

**Solution to your problem**

the new appended item did not initiate with `.draggable()` so just call `$(".draggable").last().draggable();` after your append. (since the append element will always be the last one, use `.last()` will target the last element from all `.draggable` elements)

```
  $(".itemContainer").append(
    "<span class='draggable' id='" +
    $(ui.draggable).attr("id") +
    "'>" +
    $(ui.draggable).html() +
    "</span>"
  );
  $(".draggable").last().draggable();
```

Answer (score 0):

$(selector).draggable() makes the matching elements draggable

$(tgtEl).append(html) is adding the new element.

Simply make the new item that you appended to be draggable, after you appended it

something like

```
$(html).appendTo(tgtEl).draggable();
```